# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this javascript in my view
What can I do to fix this error?

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $("#check_module").click(function () {
    IMP.init('imp45233'); //iamport 대신 자신의 "가맹점 식별코드"를 사용하시면 됩니다
    IMP.request_pay({
      merchant_uid : "<%= @merchant_uid %>",
      name : '결제테스트',
      amount : <%= @course.price %>,
      buyer_email : '<%= current_user.email %>',
      buyer_name : '<%= current_user.name %>',
      buyer_tel : ' no phone ',
      buyer_addr : ' course name: no address',
      buyer_postcode : ' no postcode ',
      m_redirect_url: ""
    }, function(rsp) {
      if ( rsp.success ) {// Successful payment: Successful payment approval or issuance of a virtual account
          window.location.href= "<%= add_enrollment_path(:course_id => @course) %>"?imp_uid=rsp.data.imp_uid&merchant_uid=rsp.data.merchant_uid;
      } else {
        var msg = '결제에 실패하였습니다.';
        msg += '에러내용 : ' + rsp.error_msg;
        alert(msg);
      }
    });
  });
<% end %>
```

I'm having problem with this line

```js
window.location.href= "<%= add_enrollment_path(:course_id => @course) %>"?imp_uid=rsp.data.imp_uid&merchant_uid=rsp.data.merchant_uid;
```

After fixing the error with the suggestion below :

```html
window.location.href= "<%= add_enrollment_path(:course_id => @course) %>?imp_uid=" + rsp.imp_uid + "&merchant_uid=" + rsp.merchant_uid;
```

Now I am running into  a different problem: I think it is related to my route:

```html
get 'enrollments/add_enrollment/', :to => 'enrollments#add_enrollment', :as => 'add_enrollment'
```

Here is the error

can't find record with friendly id: "reading-starter-01?imp_uid=imp_376842875552"

do I need to add /:course_id/ ?? I will try ^^ wish me luck

Answer (score 2):

Try building the string properly:

`"<%= add_enrollment_path(:course_id => @course) %>?imp_uid=" + rsp.data.imp_uid + "&merchant_uid=" + rsp.data.merchant_uid;`

Comment: Thank you it worked but now I am running into a different problem

Comment: @JJ: this makes it a different question then.